# Order by date in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Those are following

**Table Name : stockIn**

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+        
| Id |  date       | Itemname   | stockInqty |    
+====+=============+============+============+
| 1  | 12/12/2014  | testitem   |  12        |
| 2  | 14/12/2014  | testitem11 |  20        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+
```

**Table Name : stockOut**

```
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+
| Id | date       | Itemname    | stockOutqty |
+====+============+=============+=============+     
| 1  | 12/12/2014 | testitem    |  7          |
| 2  | 13/12/2014 | testitem11  |  15         |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I need a combined result of testitem record between two date period in the order of

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| date       | itemname  | stockInqty  | stockOutqty |
+============+===========+=============+=============+       
| 12/12/2014 | testitem  |  12         |   7         |
| 13/12/2014 | testitem  |  NIL        |   15        | 
| 14/12/2014 | testitem  |  20         |   NIL       |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

**I got a query like this**

```
SELECT t1.`date`
     , t1.itemname
     , t1.stockInqty AS stockInqty
     , t2.stockInqty AS stockOutqty
FROM tbl1 t1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
                              AND t1.itemname = t2.itemname
UNION

SELECT t2.`date`
     , t2.itemname
     , t1.stockInqty AS stockInqty
     , t2.stockInqty AS stockOutqty
FROM tbl1 t1 RIGHT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
                               AND t1.itemname = t2.itemname
```

The result of the query will be like this

```
+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+
|date         | itemname   | stockInqty | stockOutqty |    
+=============+============+============+=============+       
| 12/12/2014  | testitem   |      12    |   7         |   
| 14/12/2014  | testitem   |      20    |   NIL       |     
| 13/12/2014  | testitem   |      NIL   |   15        |
+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

The result is ordered on the basis of fist table data.

I need the result should be ordered on the basis of date (ie,first record must be on `12/12/2014`, second record on `13/14/2014` third on `14/12/2014`).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add at last order by date asc

Comment: You have two columns data which needs to be sorted in one single output - **not possible as if you will apply sort on column 1** the data will be sorts on that basis - `NIL, 12/12, 13,12` therefore the 14/12 data will be on first row.

Comment: thanks for that edit Ullas, the whole intent of the question got lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from
(
SELECT t1.date as sdate
     , t1.itemname
     , t1.stockInqty AS stockInqty
     , t2.stockInqty AS stockOutqty
FROM tbl1 t1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
                              AND t1.itemname = t2.itemname
UNION

SELECT t2.date as sdate
     , t2.itemname
     , t1.stockInqty AS stockInqty
     , t2.stockInqty AS stockOutqty
FROM tbl1 t1 RIGHT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
                               AND t1.itemname = t2.itemname
) t
order by sdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with order by date

```
SELECT t1.`date`
         , t1.itemname
         , t1.stockInqty AS stockInqty
         , t2.stockInqty AS stockOutqty
    FROM tbl1 t1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
                                  AND t1.itemname = t2.itemname
    UNION

    SELECT t2.`date`
         , t2.itemname
         , t1.stockInqty AS stockInqty
         , t2.stockInqty AS stockOutqty
    FROM tbl1 t1 RIGHT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
                                   AND t1.itemname = t2.itemname order by  date
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
select date,itemname,stockInqty,stockOutqty from(
SELECT t1.date
 , t1.itemname
 , t1.stockInqty AS stockInqty
 , t2.stockInqty AS stockOutqty
 FROM tbl1 t1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.date = t2.date 
                          AND t1.itemname = t2.itemname
UNION

SELECT t2.date
 , t2.itemname
 , t1.stockInqty AS stockInqty
 , t2.stockInqty AS stockOutqty
FROM tbl1 t1 RIGHT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.date = t2.date
                           AND t1.itemname = t2.itemname)
order by date
```